# Data-Binding Without Having Comma Between Items in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I am pulling in some data in my Angular 2 app, and right now this works:

```
            <div class="contact-container">
                <contact [id]="record._id"
                               [type]="'staff'"
                               [title]="[record.name.first, record.name.last]"></contact>
            </div>
```

Clearly, though, I don't want to have the "," between 'record.name.first' and 'record.name.last' because that's the way it will appear in the view. However, without the comma, I'm not sure how to get that info to display without errors, because they represent two different fields being pulled in from my API/database.

Is there another way I could do this to print both first and last names, but without having a character in between?

I've tried using a "getter" in my component, like this:

```
public get fullName(): string {
    return !this.record.name.first ? null : `${this.record.name.first} ${this.record.name.last}`;
}
```

... but when I try applying that like this it doesn't work:

```
            <div class="contact-container">
                <contact [id]="record._id"
                               [type]="'staff'"
                               [title]="[record.fullName]"></contact>
            </div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `[title]="record.fullName"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use good old string concatenation:

```
 <div class="contact-container">
     <contact [id]="record._id"
              [type]="'staff'"
              [title]="record.name.first + ' ' + record.name.last"></contact>
 </div>
```

Your getter probably doesn't work because it's a property of your component, not of `record`. Have you tried:

```
 <div class="contact-container">
     <contact [id]="record._id"
              [type]="'staff'"
              [title]="fullName()"></contact>
 </div>
```

Comment: To my surprise, the first of your suggestions worked. So thanks! I'm kind of surprised it worked, because I thought I'd need to pass the value via string interpolation. I didn't think straight string concatenation would work. But it did! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use a method

```
<div class="contact-container">
        <contact [id]="record._id"
                 [type]="'staff'"
                 [title]="getFullName(record.name.first, record.name.last)"></contact>
</div>
```

You method will be as

```
 getFullName(firstName:string,lastName:string)
  {
    return firstName + lastName;
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mxxVrqXpV1hE4FpHJ5Ac?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Much, much simpler, you already came up with the answer. Just bind to the fullName() function.

```
<div class="contact-container">
                <contact [id]="record._id"
                               [type]="'staff'"
                               [title]="fullName()"></contact>
            </div>
```